# Finding the number of records, sum from a different table in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

Hey I am working on a report which is giving the details of invoices for a customer. there are two tables Customer, Invoices.

I need to find out the number of invoices for each customer, total of invoices for each customer, average invoice total for each customer, average number of invoices for each customer. Below is a similar table structure.

Customer:  **CustomerNo**

Invoices: **CustomerNo, InvoiceID, Amount**

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: I tried using summary for invoiceid to count the number of invoices but it keep adding on to next customer.

Comment: Same with Total Amount

Comment: What exactly is the average number of invoices per customer?

Comment: have you made any groupings? how are you calculating summary and average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it in Sql Server, not sure if it helpful as I see the question is for Crystal Reports

```
SELECT CustomerNo, 
COUNT(1) TotalNoOfInvoices, 
SUM(Amount) TotalAmountOfInvoices
FROM Invoices
Group by CustomerNo


SELECT
COUNT(b.CustomerNo)/Count(distinct a.Customer) AvgNoOfInvoices, 
SUM(b.Amount)/Count(distinct a.Customer) AvgAmountOfInvoices
FROM Customer A LEFT JOIN Invoices B 
ON A.CustomerNo = B.CustomerNo
```

Comment: LOL AvgNoOfInvoices would always be the same thing as count(*). Presumably there is only going to ever be a single value for a CustomerNo.

Comment: Same thing with AvgAmountOfInvoices. This is the same thing as SUM(b.Amount)/1